# Map Of functions c++

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have made a map of functions. all these functions are void and receive single string parameter.

code:

```
void f1(string params){...}
void f2(string params){...}
void f3(string params){...}

map<string , void*> funcMap;

funcMap["f1"] =(void*)&f1;
funcMap["f2"] =(void*)&f2;
funcMap["f3"] =(void*)&f3;
```

how do i call a function?
I tried the next code, but id doesn't work:

```
void (*func)(string) =  &funcMap[commandType];
func(commandParam);
```

I get this error message:

```
Server.cpp:160:46: error: cannot convert ‘void**’ to ‘void (*)(std::string) {aka void (*)(std::basic_string<char>)}’ in initialization
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```cpp
using pfunc = void (*)(string);

map<string, pfunc> funcMap; 
funcMap["f1"] = f1; //and so forth
```

And then call:

```cpp
pfunc f = funcMap[commandType];
(*f)(commandParam);
```

In general, why throw away type safety? If it's a map of function pointers, declare it to be one.

Comment: Why not get the compiler to take the heat?

Comment: I didn't get that. The heat of what exactly?

Comment: Using classes and the keyword virtual (see below).

Comment: "In general, why throw away type safety?" They're not only throwing away type safety, it's also ill-defined. C and C++ do not define what happens when you convert between function pointer types and non-function pointer types.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just have those as separate classes.

Then have the methods as virtual.

You can then have a map between the string and the base class.

i.e.

```
class Someoperation
{
    virtual void Doit() = 0;
};

map<string, Someopertion> ops;
```

Then

```
class MyOp : public Someoperation
{
   void Doit() { /* Some code here */}
};
```

Just add objects

```
ops["Hello"] = MyOp();
```

then call it

```
ops["Hello"].Doit();
```

Comment: The "ops["Hello"] = MyOp();" will error out because there's no assignment from MyOp to Someoperation. You need a map of Someoperation pointers for that technique to work. And that needs dynamic allocation, and all kinds of object lifetime issues.

Comment: Try compiling. You cannot have a map of abstract type, as it's an error to construct one.

Comment: Oh, and another thing. Assining MyOp to Someoperation (objects, not pointers) does not overwrite the virtual function table pointer. Even if Doit is not abstract, the base class's implementation will be called.

Comment: I'm no expert but I think the map expects objects to be of a specific byte size and therefore would "be upset" if you give it instances of children of the class because they could be of any size. No? Sure love that avatar. This technique looks like something you'd do in a sane OOP language. :D

Comment: If Java had first class function references from day one, no one would ever suggest classes here :)

Answer (score 1):

`&funcMap[commandType]`

Just drop the `&`.  Your compile error was useful here.  It had a `void**` on the right which is because you took the *address* of a function pointer.  You don't want two levels of indirection there.

Answer (score 0):

Try C++ style. It has overhead for allocation and inheritance, but it's more flexible and extensible if you'll need some more functionality in the future.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Someoperation {
public:
    virtual void Doit() = 0;
};

class MyOp1 : public Someoperation {
public:
    void Doit() final { cout << "MyOp1" << endl; }
};

class MyOp2 : public Someoperation {
public:
    void Doit() final { cout << "MyOp2" << endl; }
};

int main() {
    unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<Someoperation> > ops;

    ops["1"] = unique_ptr<Someoperation>(new MyOp1);
    ops["2"] = unique_ptr<Someoperation>(new MyOp2);
    ops["1"]->Doit();   // Out: MyOp1
    ops["2"]->Doit();   // Out: MyOp2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, your code is longer, heavier, less readable, old fashioned and you're introducing unnecessarily instances of otherwise unneeded objects and even polymorphism.