# How can I call a function from an array of functions via its index?

Tags: c++, arrays, function

A beginner's question I couldn't find answered online, likely because I don't know the terminology.

I want to call one of a list of procedures based on a computed index value. That is, given a '1', invoke firstProc(), '2' invokes secondProc() and so on.

All the procedures are void functions with no arguments.

I can implement that with switch/case, but what I'd prefer is something like:

`void* action[2] {*firstProc, *secondProc};`

(This compiles, but warns: `invalid conversion from 'void (*)()' to 'void*'`)

and then later:

`action[get_index()]();`

The compiler objects that 'action' can't be used as a function.

This must be possible, right? I've tried several variations but I can't get past the use of the selected ('action[index]') as a function.

Comment: it is more or less clear what the issue is, nevertheless you should post a [mcve] of your code

Comment: Store it as a function pointer `void (*)()` as the warning says in your array instead of as `void*`. Or use `std::function<>`.

Comment: `void*` is just a pointer to nothing, it can point anywhere but there is not much you can do with it

Comment: Related: [Why can't I cast a function pointer to (void *)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36645660/11082165) and [Function pointers casting in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096341/11082165)

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040203/map-of-functions-c

Comment: @NathanOliver I think that'd be good to close on.

Comment: `using fnptr = void(*)();` and `fnptr action[2]{&firstproc, &secondproc};`

Comment: `void*` is a **data** pointer; it cannot legally be used as a pointer to a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two equivalent ways* to do what you want. The explanation is given as comments in the code snippets.

#### Method 1

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
void foo2() 
{ 
    std::cout << " wolrd!"; 
    
}


int main()
{
   
    void (*a)() = foo;// a is a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and also does not return anything
    
    void (*b)() = foo2;// b is a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and also does not return anything
    
    
    //create array(of size 2) that can hold pointers to functions that does not return anything and also does not take any parameter
    void (*arr[2])() = { a, b};
    
    arr[0](); // calls foo 
    
    arr[1](); //calls foo1
    
    return 0;
}
```

Method 1 can be executed [here](https://onlinegdb.com/phDfV2fQA).

In method 1 above `void (*a)() = foo;` **means** that `a` is a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and also does not return anything.

Similarly, `void (*b)() = foo2;` **means** that `b` is a pointer to a function that takes no parameter and also does not return anything.

Next, `void (*arr[2])() = { a, b};` **means** that `arr` is an array(of size 2) that can hold pointers to functions that does not return anything and also does not take any parameter.

#### Method 2

```
#include <iostream>
void foo() 
{ 
    std::cout << "Hello";
}
void foo2() 
{ 
    std::cout << " wolrd!"; 
    
}


int main()
{
   
    //create array(of size 2) that can hold pointers to functions that does not return anything
    void (*arr[2])() = { foo, foo2};
    
    arr[0](); // calls foo 
    
    arr[1](); //calls foo1
    
    return 0;
}
```

Method 2 can be executed [here](https://onlinegdb.com/P91pAX1hj).

Comment: Thanks. Your method 2 is very close to what I had tried, just a slip of the syntax away (-: . I've modified the array declaration and the rest works as I'd hoped.

Comment: @JimMack You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You need the correct syntax for your function pointer array. `void(*func_ptr[])()`.

Example:

```
void func1() { std::cout << "Hallo" << std::endl; }
void func2() { std::cout << "World" << std::endl; }

// if you need a different signature for your functions like:
int func3(int n) { std::cout << "n1 " << n << std::endl; return n*2; }
int func4(int n) { std::cout << "n2 " << n << std::endl; return n*3; }

int main()
{
    // array of function pointer which
    // have no parameter and void as return value
    void(*func_ptr[])()={ func1, func2 };

    for ( unsigned int idx = 0; idx<2; idx++ )
    {
        func_ptr[idx]();
    }

    // array of function pointers with int return value and int as
    // parameter
    int(*func_ptr2[])(int)={ func3, func4 };

    for ( unsigned int idx = 0; idx<2; idx++ )
    {
        std::cout << "retval: " << func_ptr2[idx](6) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've stopped using function pointers (though they still can be useful).
I usually use std::function (and lambdas) when working with functions

Code for arrays of functions then look like this.
I used std::vector but std::array for fixed size should work fine too.

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void some_function()
{
    std::cout << "some function\n";
}

int main()
{
    // std::function, abstraction of a function, function signature = template parameter, so void () is  function returning a void, no parameters
    // std::vector, runtime resizable array
    // constructor : 4 time a lambda function printing out hello world.
    std::vector<std::function<void()>> functions(4, [] { std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; } );

    // easy syntax to assign an existing function to an index
    functions[1] = some_function;
    
    // replace a function in the vector with another one (lambda)
    functions[2] = [] { std::cout << "booh\n"; };

    // call function at index 0
    functions[0]();
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // or loop over all the functions and call them (classic for loop)
    for (std::size_t n = 0; n < functions.size(); ++n) functions[n]();
    std::cout << "\n\n";

    // or loop over all the functions (range based for loop)
    for (const auto& function : functions) function();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the modern approach. Although I'd add a word of caution that calling through function requires a virtual function call and vector will dynamically allocate memory by default. Maybe not a problem for some applications but I'd avoid them in hot paths of software like simulations or games.

Comment: `std::function` is an expensive analog to a function pointer. If you don't need the argument- and return-type matching that it provides, it's wasted time and code space. Labelling it "the modern approach" is marketing hype.

Comment: I agree that "modern" is the wrong label for `std::function`. It is rather the type-erased way of doing it. When there is no need to erase any type information, it comes with unnecessary overhead and no apparent benefit compared to a good old function pointer. I am not saying it is bad, but it shouldn't be confused with the default goto solution for any function

Comment: I think its my background, we use lambdas/std::functions a lot, the capture capabilities of the lambdas (and storing them in functions) is desirable in a multithreaded environment. And right they sure aren't zero cost abstractions so I wouldn't use them in embedded/time critical places either. And I will refrain from using the word "modern" in the future. I stand corrected